# How to use a custom analyser on specific elasticsearch documents

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I have a custom analyser that I want to use on only specific documents that have the table entity_type, how would I go about that?

Document I want to match:

```
{
  ... other keys

  "_source": {
    "entity_type": "table"  // <-- I want to match this and use the custom analyser on this entire document
  }
}
```

Custom analyser (currently just set to the default but I want it to only affect tables)

```py
elasticsearch.indices.create(
  index="myIndex",
  body={
    "settings": {
      "analysis": {
        "char_filter": {
          "underscore_to_dash": {
            "type": "mapping",
            "mappings": ["_ => -"],
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "default": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": ["lowercase"],
            "char_filter": ["underscore_to_dash"],
          }
        },
      },
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Analyzer can only be applied to a specific field. So in your case it might make sense to have 2 fields and use one for `"entity_type": "table"` and another for other docs.